# Representing "unless" in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

I am trying to represent the following statement, which contains "unless", into propositional logic:

**If it's snowing when I am outdoors I get cold unless I am wearing a coat.**

Using the following propositions:

**Snowing, Outdoor, Cold, WearingCoat**

Here's my attempt however I am not sure if it's the right representation:

$$(Snowing \land WearingCoat \land Outdoor) \to -Cold  $$

Comment: "I get cold unless I am wearing a coat" should probably be interpreted as "if I'm not wearing a coat, I get cold".  That makes more sense to me than interpreting it as "if I am wearing a coat, I don't get cold"

Comment: Note that you imply that if it's not snowing you can't get cold.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what *proportional* logic is (it sounds neat!), but as Brian suggests in the comments, the standard logical interpretation of "unless" is *if not*. Under this interpretation, "I get cold unless I am wearing a coat" means I get cold if I am not wearing a coat, and can be represented formally as
$$\lnot\text{WearingCoat}\rightarrow\text{Cold}$$
To motivate this interpretation of "unless", consider a statement like "We won't make the train unless you hurry." When I say this, I'm saying that if you don't hurry, we're not going to make the train. I'm *not* saying that if you do hurry, we're going to make the train.

With that said, the entire statement "If it's snowing when I am outdoors, [then] I get cold unless I am wearing a coat" could be represented as
$$(\text{Snowing}\land\text{Outdoor})\rightarrow(\lnot\text{WearingCoat}\rightarrow\text{Cold})$$
or equivalently
$$(\text{Snowing}\land\text{Outdoor}\land\lnot\text{WearingCoat})\rightarrow\text{Cold}$$